# If $X$ is inseparable, must $Y$ be inseparable?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry, separable-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces. Suppose that there is linear isometry $T: X \rightarrow Y$, namely that $\Vert Tx\Vert =\Vert x\Vert$ for all $x\in X$.

If $X$ is inseparable, must $Y$ be inseparable?

And if $Y$ is inseparable, must $X$ be inseparable?

Comment: $X$ is an isometrically isomorphic copy of a subspace of $Y$. So, you are effectively asking on the one hand if a subspace of a separable space is necessarily separable.

Comment: My gut says that if $X$ is inseparable then $Y$ must be too. $T: X \to Y$ is an injection so $Y$ is "bigger" than $X$, so surely it's harder to find a countable dense subset of $Y$ than it is for $X$, no?

Comment: OTOH $Y$ being inseparable would probably not mean $X$ is inseparable in general. The example I'm thinking of is $X = \mathbb R$, and $Y$ is some uncountably infinite dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space. Not sure that the latter is actually metrizable though!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 5):

$X=\textrm{c}_{00}$ and $Y=\ell_{\infty}$ both equipped with $\|⋅\|_{\infty}$ norm.

Consider $T:X\to Y$ defined by $Tx=x$

Then $T$ is a linear isometry.

$(\textrm{c}_{00}, \|⋅\|_{\infty})$ is separable but $(\ell_{\infty}, \|⋅\|_{\infty}) $ is not separable.

> $Y$ non separable doesn't imply $X$ non separable.

---

But the other way is true. $X$ is not separable implies $Y$ is not separable. Contrapositively $Y$ separable implies $X$ separable.

$T:X\to Y$ linear isometry implies $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to $T(X) \subset Y$.
Now if $Y$ is separable then $T(X) $ is separable implies $X$ separable.

> $X$ non separable implies $Y$ non separable.